# Overloading << operator error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm getting an error on this operator overload.  Here is the error that I'm getting:

> Angle.cpp:466: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in
>   '(+out)->std::basic_ostream<_Elem,     _Traits>::operator<< [with
>   _Elem = char, _Traits = std::char_traits](((const Angle*)this)->Angle::
>       getDegrees()) << "\37777777660"'

Here is my class to overload the `<<` operator

```
#ifndef OUTPUTOPS_H
#define OUTPUTOPS_H 1

#include <ostream>
#include "BoolOut.h"

// Prints the output of an object using cout. The object
// must define the function output()
template< class T >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const T& x)
{
    x.output(out);

    return out;
}

#endif // OUTPUTOPS_H
```

The problem happens here:

```
void Angle::output(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out << getDegrees() << "°";
}
```

Which oddly enough happens not from `getDegrees()` but from the string. I tried changing the string to something like, "hello" just to make sure that it wasn't the symbol but I received the same error.

Here is the rest of the code excluding unrelated code:

```
// Angle.h

#include "OutputOps.h"
// End user added include file section

#include <vxWorks.h>
#include <ostream>

class Angle {

public:
    // Default constructor/destructor
    ~Angle();

    // User-defined methods
    //
    // Default Constructor sets Angle to 0.
    Angle();
    //
    ...
    // Returns the value of this Angle in degrees.
    double getDegrees() const;
    ...
    // Prints the angle to the output stream as "x°" in degrees
    void output(std::ostream& out) const;

};

#endif // ANGLE_H


//  File Angle.cpp

#include "MathUtility.h"
#include <math.h>
// End user added include file section

#ifndef Angle_H
#include "Angle.h"
#endif


Angle::~Angle()
{
    // Start destructor user section
    // End destructor user section
}

//
// Default Constructor sets Angle to 0.
Angle::Angle() :
radians( 0 )
{
}

...
//
// Returns the value of this Angle in degrees.
double Angle::getDegrees() const
{
    return radians * DEGREES_PER_RADIAN;
}

//
// Returns the value of this Angle in semicircles.
...

//
// Prints the angle to the output stream as "x°" in degrees
void Angle::output(std::ostream& out) const
{
    out << getDegrees() << "°";
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an included ostream& operator<<(ostream &, char *) or ostream & operator<<(ostream &, string &) ?  In which case, the compiler can't choose between that included one and your template <class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream, T&), they both apply.

Comment: You define `operator<<` for **all** types. Obviously it conflicts with `operator<<` which is already defined for some types such as `std::string`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout <<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319190/ambiguous-overload-for-operator-in-stdcout)

Comment: @n.m. I wanted to be able to ask the question again, but now have a better understanding. When I first asked it, I didn't understand the problem, and wouldn't be able to understand the answers I was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use template in your overloaded operator<<, but this overload is not in class, so you can't set typename T. In other words, you have to overload operator<< for every type of variable which you would like to use or overload this operator in class which also is a template. For example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Angle& x)
{
    x.output(out);

    return out;
}
```

This error means that compiler can't predict what kind of variables will be used there.

---

You overload this operator for all possible data, so when you pass getDegrees() function, which returns double then i don't think that x.output(out); will work ;) (hint x will be double)

Comment: Template was being used because this overload will be used for multiple different variables being passed to it. This code is also legacy code that is being updated slightly, so I know this has worked in the past, but now it won't.

Comment: You overload this operator for all possible data, so when you pass getDegrees() function, which returns double then i don't think that x.output(out); will work ;) (hint x will be double)