# C++ print template container error (error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<') understanding?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write template function which can print container like `std::vector`, std::list.

Below is my function, just overload `<<`.

```
template<typename Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c){
    for(auto item:c){
        out<<item;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Test code as below:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> iVec{5, 9, 1, 4, 6};
    std::cout<<iVec<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ouput:

```
59146
```

And I want to add a space string in each value(output like `5 9 1 4 6`), so I change the function to:

```
template<typename Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c){
    for(auto item:c){
        out<<item<<" ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then it get error:

```
merror: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const char [2]')
         out<<item<<" ";
```

I know `<<` can output common type like.

```
int a = 0;
double f = 0.3;
std::string s = "123";
std::cout<<a<<f<<s<<std::endl;
```

So Why get the above error ? And is there any way to solve it?

I have see this question [Ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout <<](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319190/6329006) but I still can't understand clearly.

All code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c){
    for(auto item:c){
        out<<item;
        // out<<item<<" "; // error
    }
    return out;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> iVec{5, 9, 1, 4, 6};
    std::cout<<iVec<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].  Thanks.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of text.

Comment: Answer 2 in the Q&A you linked is bang on. The problem is `const Container& c` is too broad. It can literally be anything. A container, a string, an integer, a wombat... you name it. You've would up with a templated `<<` that can replace all `<<` overloads, so the poor compiler doesn't know which `<<`it should use, yours or the one intended to be used with `char` array.

Comment: @PaulSanders , I have update all code.

Comment: @PasserBy, picture is just for, that the code is right and more understandable.

Comment: I have remove the picture, I don't think is there any wrong.

Comment: To be honest that picture wasn't that odious. The problem with images is they are much harder to search than text, opaque  to the visually impaired, often blocked by firewalls, the link rots, can't be compiled, and worst of all, used in place of of an actual problem explanation. Your image was supplemental information, an extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring `template<typename Container>` could be dangerous as this template includes 'all' variable types `int`, `char` etc. Due to this compiler does not know which `operator<<` to use.

In order to take only container type variables use template of templates.
Here is working code for you

```
template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container<T, std::allocator<T>>& c) {
    for (auto item : c) {
        out << item << " ";
    } 
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    int arr[] = { 0,3,6,7 };
    vector<int> v(arr, arr+4);
    cout << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that gets pretty funky for containers that don't follow that pattern, though.   It's actually quite hard to do fully generically.

Comment: This works well, and is what i am looking for, but I still can't  understand clearly.

Comment: Yes, `template <typename Container>` would match `int`, but unlike `const char*` it isn't ambiguous (see working code in OP by @Jayhello). As pointed out by @user4581301, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319889) answer is "bang on".

Comment: This did not work for me with `set<double>`.

Answer (score 4):

@miradham explained the issue very well.

but this a more generic solution using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to make the overload considered only for types on which the range-based for loop can be used, what ever their template arguments can be.

type coming form `std::basic_string` were ignored to prevent ambiguity with the standard `operator <<` to display strings

c-style array will not be displayed using this overload even though they could because they are decayed to pointers and displayed with the standard `operator <<`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <string>

template<template<typename...> typename From, typename T>
struct is_from : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> typename From, typename ... Ts>
struct is_from<From, From<Ts...> > : std::true_type {};

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_input_iterator : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_input_iterator<T,
    void_t<decltype(++std::declval<T&>()),
           decltype(*std::declval<T&>()),
           decltype(std::declval<T&>() == std::declval<T&>())>>
    : std::true_type { };

template<typename Container, 
typename std::enable_if<is_input_iterator<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container>()))>::value &&
                        is_input_iterator<decltype(std::end(std::declval<Container>()))>::value &&
                        !is_from<std::basic_string, Container>::value, int>::type = 0>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c){
    for(const auto& item:c){
        out << item << " ";
    }
    return out;
}

int main(){

    std::array<int, 6> arr{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> vec{5, 9, 1, 4, 6};

    std::cout << vec << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string("test") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not compile in MSVC 2017.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the templated type Container can match any type, not just containers.  That includes the `" "` you are trying to print.

If you look at the error message from a different compiler: https://godbolt.org/g/3YKtca

```
<source>:5:15: note: candidate function [with Container = char [2]]

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c){
```

Perhaps you want a partial specialization of `vector<T>` to only take vectors.   Determining if a type is a container is a more complicated problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename E, typename A>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<E, A>& c){
    for(auto item:c){
        out<<item;
        out<<item<<" "; // error
    }
    return out;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> iVec{5, 9, 1, 4, 6};
    std::cout<<iVec<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/NJNwmN

Comment: @user4581301 a partial specialization on vector is probably the happy median between fully generic and an explicit specialization on vector<int> (responding to original comment)

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking in terms of simplest possible to make it easier on the asker, but you framed the more complicated option simply. Hard to do that sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `operator<<` that you defined matches for both `std::vector` and `const char (&array)[N]` (the type of `" "` that you try to stream to `out`).

A simplified code example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Container& c)
{
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The following example would restrict `operator<<` to `std::vector`s only:

```
template<typename ... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<Args...>& c)
{
    for(auto item:c){
        out<<item<<" ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/174ed87c8328dbdd).