# C++ generic overload of operator<< for STL containers produces ambiguous overload error with strings

Tags: c++, string, stl, c++17, operator-overloading

I mean to write a generic overload of `operator<<` to print STL containers.
I put together code below.
Whenever `operator<<` involves a `string`, it produces a compilation error `ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'`, in the example in *problem lines 1 and 2*.

**How can I get rid of the error, without losing the generic overload, and without having to write explicit instantiations for every possible use of containers with strings?**
Perhaps excluding from my overload the strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

// Maximum number of printed values. After this, print "..."
#define MAX_PRINT_VALS 10

//=========================================================================
// Set of functions to dump STL containers

template <template <class...> class Container, class ...T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Container<T...>& c)
{
    os << "[";

    size_t nvals = 0;
    for ( auto iter = c.begin() ; iter != c.end() ; iter++ ) {
        os << *iter;
        nvals++;
        if (iter != --c.end())
            os << ", ";
        if (nvals > MAX_PRINT_VALS) {
           os << "... (total of " << c.size() << " values)";
           break;
        }
    }

    os << "]";
    return os;
}

template<class Key, class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<Key, T>& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
    //os << std::endl;
    return os;
}


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //============================================================
    // Print vector
    const size_t nmax = 3;
    vector<double const*> vec_dp;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < nmax; n++) {
        vec_dp.push_back(new double(n+1.5));
    }
    cout << "Vector of indices vec_dp = " << vec_dp << endl;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < nmax; n++) {
        delete vec_dp[n];
    }

    vector<string> vec_s;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < nmax; n++) {
        vec_s.push_back("asa");
    }
    cout << "Vector of string vec_s = " << vec_s << endl;         // PROBLEM LINE 1

    //============================================================
    // Print set
    set<double> set_d;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < nmax; n++) {
        set_d.insert(n+1.3);
    }
    cout << "Set of double set_d = " << set_d << endl;

    //============================================================
    // Print list
    list<double> list_d;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < (nmax + 10); n++) {
        list_d.emplace_back(n+1.4);
    }
    cout << "List of double list_d = " << list_d << endl;

    //============================================================
    // Print map
    typedef pair<int, int> pair2_t;
    map<pair2_t::first_type, pair2_t::second_type> map_i_i;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < (nmax + 10); n++) {
        map_i_i.insert(pair2_t(n+1, n+2));
    }
    cout << "Map of (int, int) map_i_i = " << map_i_i << endl;

    typedef pair<int, string> pair1_t;
    map<pair1_t::first_type, pair1_t::second_type> map_i_s;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < (nmax + 10); n++) {
        map_i_s.insert(pair1_t(n+1, "one"));
    }
    cout << "Map of (int, string) map_i_s = " << map_i_s << endl;         // PROBLEM LINE 2


    return 0;
}
```

**Related**

1. [C++ print template container error (error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<') understanding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531514/c-print-template-container-error-error-ambiguous-overload-for-operator)
2. [Ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319190/ambiguous-overload-for-operator-in-stdcout)
3. [overloading << operator for c++ stl containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319813/overloading-operator-for-c-stl-containers)
4. [Narrowing down a C++ concept to exclude certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912163/narrowing-down-a-c-concept-to-exclude-certain-types)

Comment: `std::string` is also a container.

Comment: @273K -  I know that. Any possible solution? 
Perhaps excluding from my overload the strings (I don't know if that is possible)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please tag the used C++ version.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio You can use [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and SFINAE with C++17 as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77321100/12002570)

Comment: You can exclude strings but that's probably not enough. Your catch-all `<<` will catch every single class template, whether it is a container or not.

Comment: It is a bad idea to provide (generic) operator for types you don't own. You might have ODR violation when/if the type provide that operator in a later version. Wrapping it in your own stream might be fine though.

Comment: @Jarod42 not a problem, put your operator in a namespace and throw in some `using`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get rid of the error, without losing the generic overload, and without having to write explicit instantiations for every possible use of containers with strings? **Perhaps excluding from my overload the strings**

You can use `std::enable_if`(since you're using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) to **exclude your own overload for** `std::string` as shown below:

```
template <template <class... K> class Container, class ...T   >  
//added this to make use of SFINAE
std::enable_if_t<not (std::is_same_v<std::string, Container<T...>>),std::ostream&>                     operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Container<T...>& c)   
{                  
    //other code as before...

    os << "]";
    return os;
}
//other code as before...
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     //other code as before...
     cout << "Vector of string vec_s = " << vec_s << endl; //works now    
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MEdfbq46a)

---

With [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you could instead make use of `requires` and perhaps can make the code more readable. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zx9E7sj6P)

Comment: The C++17 version works great for every case I tested so far, except for one: `array<T, n>`.
I had to write a separate `operator<<` for it. A couple of minor questions arose:
1. I had to replace `--a.end()` with `(a.end() - 1)` in `array<T, n>::operator<<`, to remove compilation error `lvalue required as decrement operand`, Why?.
2. I cannot use `for ( const auto & iter...` instead of `for ( auto iter...`Why?
3. Is there a way to encompass `array<T, n>::operator<<` in my generic overload?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Feel free to create/ask a new separate question for the follow up questions(that are not related to this original question) as the comment section has word limit and also formatting issues. Also, I've seen that comments get deleted many times without any warning so writing the answer(for the follow up questions) here in comment box should be avoided.

Comment: This will still allow his operator to pick up any class other than `std::string`, even if it isn't a container. This can be avoided by adding additional `enable_if` -- if I only want a container, I'll usually use an `enable_if` on the presence of a member function `begin`, although this isn't really 100%.